# The four-penny problem

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

Suppose you have four pennies, say $P_1$ , $P_2$ ,
$P_3$ , and $P_4$ , a weighing balance with two pans, and a set of weights. You are allowed to make only four weighings of the pennies. In each weighing, you may place some (possibly none) of the pennies in the left pan, some (possibly none) in the right pan, and leave the remaining pennies (if any) off the balance.

The problem is this: How should the four  weighings be designed so as to produce the most accurate determination of the weights of the four pennies, in the sense that the sum of the variances of the four weight estimators should be
as small as possible?

Wee assume that weighings are independent and that measuring errors
have mean $0$ and a common variance, say $\sigma^2$ , that does not depend on the configuration of pennies on the scale.

Let $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$, $\beta_3$, $\beta_4$ be the unknown weights of the four pennies.

For $i = 1,...,4$, let $W_i$ be the random variable recording the result of the $i^th$ weighting; adopt the convention that weights placed in the
left (respectively, right) pan are treated as being positive (respectively, negative).

The assumptions of the problem imply that for any given weighing design, the random vector $W=(W_1 ,W_2 ,W_3 ,W_4 )^T$ is weakly spherical and for each $i$, $$E(W_i)=\sum^4_{j=1}x_{ij}\beta_j$$ where $$
x_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
-1,& \text{if penny} ~j~ \text{is to be placed in the left pan}\\
0,& \text{if penny} ~j~ \text{is to be left off the balance}\\
1,& \text{if penny} ~j~ \text{is to be placed in the right pan}
\end{cases}
$$ 
in the $i^th$ weighing.

The four-penny problem then be restated as follows:

For what weighing design, that is, for what $4\times 4$ (nonsingular) design matrix $X=(x_{ij})$ having for its elements only $1$’s, $0$’s, and $−1$’s, is $$\sum^4_{j=1} Var(\hat{\beta}_j)$$
the smallest? Where $\hat\beta_j=\langle cv(\beta_j),W\rangle$ a Gauss-Markov estimator of $\beta_j$, with the coefficient vector $cv(\beta_i)$.

Comment: What is $\hat{\beta}_j$?

Comment: Doesn't everything depend on the set of weights available to you?

Comment: Is it $(X^{\top}X)^{-1}XW$? Then u need to minimize $\sigma^2\operatorname{tr}([X^{\top}X]^{-1})$.

Comment: Care to engage with the comments, Evgeny?

Comment: Sorry guys for late communication. I didn't have time to overthink your comments. I even don't know yet if it is any error in the text of the question. Will communicate as soon as possible.